# Learning how to define a method in ruby

Tags: ruby

Can't get this to run. What am I missing?

```
def link(address, text)
  "<a href='#{address}'>#{text}">
end

p link("https://www.google.com", "Google!")
```

Comment: Typo - watch where that double-quote ends.  This is, of course, notwithstanding of the incorrectness of the anchor tag though.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for the opening and closing quotes:

```
def link(address, text)
  "<a href='#{address}'>#{text}</a>"
end
```

Btw. in Rails you could use:

```
<%= link_to(text, address) %>
```